# Problems occurred when importing subtitles into Sony DVD Architect

Tags: encoding, subtitles, dvd

I'm new to Sony DVD Architect, I can't import subtitles into DVD-Arc even though the file extension is *.sub*. I used [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/) to save my original subtitle file(in *.ass* format) to DVDSubtitle(.sub) and Sony DVDArchitect(.sub), but it shows this error :

> "Warning: An error occurred while opening one or more files. The reason for the error could not be determined."

I then tried to save the *.ass* subtitle to DVD Subtitle System(.txt), it works, but it shows a bunch of symbols instead of the proper characters (I'm preparing  chinese subtitles by the way). The subtitles encoding is UTF-8, but it still cannot display chinese subtitles.Why?